# Evaluate $\cos(-400)\csc(-130)$

Tags: trigonometry

Please explain how to *simplify / evaluate* without a calculator... **One step at a time.** I have gotten it to

$$\cos(40)\csc(-50)$$

and I do not know where to go from there, thank you.

Comment: Think about how you could input $\csc$ into a calculator, given its definition.

Comment: 1/ Sin (-40) ?? would it still be negative?

Comment: $\frac{1}{\sin(-50)}$, but yeah.

Comment: so i have cos(40)x1/Sin (-50) how do i get it to an actual number?

Comment: Read grixor's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $$\csc(-x) = \frac{1}{\sin(-x)} = \frac{1}{-\sin(x)} = \frac{1}{-\cos(x+\pi/2)}.$$

The second equality comes from the fact that $\sin$ is an odd function, and the third equality can be easily seen by looking at the graphs of $\sin$ and $\cos$ (graph transformation).